# A question about UE

Tags: exp-time-algorithms, nexp, unique-solution

Much has been written about the class **UP** see related (even more in literature) 
**example**  [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19746/intuition-for-the-up-class)  here. Much is understood about the class **UP**, and its place in collapsing the **PH** too. **UP** has a played a part in understanding randomized reductions, too. The class (birefly) **UE** on the other hand is the class of problems recognized by an unambiguous nondeterministic TM running in exponential time with a linear exponent. The  [Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:U) reference briefly mentions its relation to **E**, as **UP** is to **P**.

Many-one reducibilities in this regime could mean that the reductions run in exponential time. A natural question that arises about **UE** under these reductions is that if **E = UE**, does **NEXP** have sparse languages that are **NEXP**-hard?